# XOR and logical conjunction

Tags: expression, xor, quantum-computing, bitwise-xor

I'm struggling in order to understand the meaning of the following expression:

```
aᵢ ⊕ bᵢ = xᵢ ∧ yᵢ
```

I know the symbol `⊕` is actually an `exclusive OR`, and the `∧` is an `and` symbol.

But I cannot grasp the overall meaning. What does that mean in simple words?
The context is what is stated [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/pubs/diqkd.pdf).
Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think that the ∧ symbol here is being used as Bitwise AND, i.e. the number such that for each binary digit, that digit is a 1 if and only if that digit is a 1 in both xi and yi.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer to this question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The paper you reference uses notation a⊕b = x·y, but · and ∧ mean the same in this context: logical AND operation on single-bit variables.

This equality describes the requirement of the CHSH game. The game involves two players, Alice and Bob, who cannot communicate with one another. They are each given a single random bit (Alice gets X and Bob gets Y). Alice and Bob then output a single bit they choose independently based on their input bits (A from Alice and B from Bob) with the goal of satisfying the formula X · Y = A ⊕ B.

This game illustrates that quantum entanglement enables strategies that are dramatically better than the purely classical strategies. The best
classical strategy is for Alice and Bob to output 0 regardless of the input - this strategy wins the game 75% of the time. But a quantum strategy exists that allows them to win 85% of the time if they share an entangled pair of qubits before the start of the game.

You can read more on the CHSH game [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/blob/master/samples/algorithms/chsh-game/Game.qs#L53).

Comment: actually I would like to ask you a few more questions about the paper ...something I don't really understand ...rounds for example...does that mean input? Then.... If
this fraction is smaller than...a formula...I think I'm not allowed to ask these questions here...

Comment: This kind of questions are really better received at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ - as an extra benefit, you'll get attention of people who know a lot more about quantum computing than I do!

Comment: I did what you suggested but so far nobody has replied to my questions...

Comment: It might take more than 6 hours... :-) Quantum computing is a much smaller community than general StackOverflow, and on top of that it's Christmas week.

Comment: thanks a lot . what I asked...it might sound trivial but not for me...